# jQuery use var in a different function

Tags: jquery, function, onclick, var

Wondering if you could give me a hand, i'm pretty new to jQuery and just been messing around building a to-do list app however stuck on the delete modal. i was wondering if it is possible to get the below to work.

```
$(".todo-delete").click(function(){
  var eld = $(this).parent();
  $( ".modal" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" ); 
});
  $(".yes").click(function(){
      $(eld).parent().parent().remove(); 
});
  $(".no").click(function(){
  $( ".modal" ).fadeToggle( "fast", "linear" ); 
});
```

I cant call the variable globally either as its using $(this).parent to select the item to delete providing the user presses "yes"

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare your variable earlier (global variable) and you don't need to use `$(eld)`, it is already jQuery element:

```
var eld;

$(".todo-delete").click(function() {
  eld = $(this).parent();
  $(".modal").fadeToggle("fast", "linear"); 
});

$(".yes").click(function() {
  eld.parent().parent().remove(); 
});

$(".no").click(function() {
  $(".modal").fadeToggle("fast", "linear"); 
});
```

Comment: Ahh wasn't aware you can declare and then add into it at a later stage. Thank you very much